# for loop that cycles between 0 and 1 in a 2D Array

Tags: java, processing

I am currently making a chessboard and I need to assign every other cell with 1 or 0 with a double for loop.
My code looks like this:
(Processing / Java)

```
int[][] board = new int [8][8];
    
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        board[i][j] = ?;
        println(board[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Before the loops: `int value = 0;`, in the loops: `board[i][j] = (value++) % 2;`

Comment: You do not actually want to cycle, when the first row transitions to the second row you repeat a 0 or 1 because otherwise the first row and the second row will be equal.

Comment: For sure you don't want to use `println` for every inner cycle.

Comment: why you don't use double at the beginning?

Comment: The desired outcome is to loop through the board alternating between 0 and 1 to ultimately assign colors to each cell depending on the value of the cell.

Comment: As an alternative, you could check whether `i` and `j` are both odd or both even. In that case you put 1, otherwise 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int[][] board = new int[8][8];

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        board[i][j] = (j+i) % 2;
        System.out.println(board[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're trying to assign color to a chessBoard.

```
0 - Black
1 - White
```

what you can do is,

```
if((i + j) % 2 == 0)
   arr[i][j] = 0;
else 
   arr[i][j] = 1;
```

Comment: "Looks like you're trying to..." are you MS Office's Clipper? :P

Comment: You can inline that `if` to just `arr[i][j] = (i + j) % 2` (same as other answer).

Comment: yes, added the if to be more clear on the explanation part @luk2302